# Variance of a Mixture [Solved]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, mixture-distribution

**Problem:** Let $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$ be density functions, and let $a$ be a constant such that
$0\le a\le 1.$ Consider the function $f(y)=af_1(y)+(1-a)f_2(y).$

1. Show that $f(y)$ is a density function. Such a density function is often referred to as a 
   mixture of two density functions.
2. Suppose that $Y_1$ is a random variable with density function $f_1(y),$ and that 
   $E(Y_1)=\mu_1$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)=\sigma_1^2;$ and similarly suppose that $Y_2$ is a
   random variable with density function $f_2(y),$ and that $E(Y_2)=\mu_2$ and
   $\operatorname{Var}(Y_2)=\sigma_2^2.$ Assume that $Y$ is a random variable whose density is a
   mixture of the densities corresponding to $Y_1$ and $Y_2.$

   (i) Show that $E(Y)=a\mu_1+(1-a)\mu_2.$

   (ii) Show that $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=a\sigma_1^2+(1-a)\sigma_2^2+a(1-a)[\mu_1-\mu_2]^2.$
   [Hint: $E(Y_i^2)=\mu_i^2+\sigma_i^2,\;i=1,2.$]

**My Work So Far:**

1. Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are non-negative, and $a$ and $1-a$ are also non-negative, it follows 
   that $f$ is non-negative. We integrate:
   \begin{align*}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)\,dy
   &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}[af_1(y)+(1-a)f_2(y)]\,dy\\
   &=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(y)\,dy+(1-a)\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2(y)\,dy\\
   &=a+1-a\\
   &=1,
   \end{align*}
   as required.
2. (i) We have
   \begin{align*}
   E(Y)
   &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\,f(y)\,dy\\
   &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\,[af_1(y)+(1-a)f_2(y)]\,dy\\
   &=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\,f_1(y)\,dy+(1-a)\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\,f_2(y)\,dy\\
   &=aE(Y_1)+(1-a)E(Y_2),
   \end{align*}
   as expected.

   (ii) We compute
   \begin{align*}
   \operatorname{Var}(Y)
   &=a^2\operatorname{Var}(Y_1)+(1-a)^2\operatorname{Var}(Y_2)+2a(1-a)\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)\\
   &=a^2\sigma_1^2+(1-a)^2\sigma_2^2+2a(1-a)[E(Y_1Y_2)-\mu_1\mu_2].
   \end{align*}
   We can arrive at this expression also by expanding out $V(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2.$ I see no way to
   simplify this. Indeed, if we assume $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, then the variances merely
   add, because the covariance disappears. It looks wrong to me, but I have verified that the identity holds for a couple of uniform distributions. I keep going around in circles on this one. Any ideas?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608/.

Comment: @whuber: Yep, that was what I needed. In particular, $E(Y^2)=aE(Y_1^2)+(1-a)E(Y_2^2)$ is what I was missing. Thanks much!