# Find the variance-covariance matrix for a linear combination of multiple bivariate normal distribution?

Tags: covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have an arbitrary number of independnet bivariate normal distributions with $\mu_i = [x_i,z_i]$ & $ \Sigma_i=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
\sigma^2_{x_i} & \sigma^2_{x_i,z_i}\\\ 
\sigma^2_{x_i, z_i} & \sigma^2_{z_i}
\end{array}\right)
$

Where i is arbitrarily large

I want to take a linear combination of these bivariate normal distributions with weights $c = [c_1,...,c_i]$ where $\sum c_i = 1$ & $c_i >0$

Obviously, the linear combination of $\mu_{mixture} = [\sum c_ix_i,\sum c_iz_i]$

However, I am not sure about the linear combination of the variance-covariance matrix.

Does anyone know how I can calculate this pooled & weighted variance-covariance? Looking for the variance-covariance matrix for the mixture distribution.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Are you interested in properties of (a) the distribution of a linear combination of random variables having these distributions or (b) a *mixture* of these distributions?

Comment: @whuber Interested in the weighted mixture distribution of the i bivariate normal distributions

Comment: Please edit your post to state that clearly, because the answer that has been posted starts off with the other interpretation.

Comment: @whuber - thanks for catching that. I have edited the post

Comment: Your question has been asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16608

Comment: @whuber thanks for adding this link. It was very helpful. I am still missing that last piece of how to apply that result to calculate the new mixture 2x2 variance-covariance matrix. The result you posted makes sense for $\sigma^2_{x}$ & $\sigma^2_{z}$, but how does this translate to the covariance $\sigma^2_{xz}$?

Comment: That result applies directly to *all* moments, without exception.  The covariance can be computed from three such moments: the expectation of $XZ,$ the expectation of $X,$ and the expectation of $Z.$  Each of those three expectations is a linear combination of expectations of the mixture components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i\stackrel{\text{indep}}\sim\mathcal N(\mu_i,\Omega_i)$ and let $S = \sum_{i=1}^n c_iX_i$. A linear combination of independent Gaussians is Gaussian so we just need the mean and covariance. By linearity we have
$$
\text E[S] = \sum_i c_i\mu_i
$$
and by independence we have
$$
\text{Var}[S] = \sum_i \text{Var}[c_iX_i] = \sum_i c_i^2 \Omega_i
$$
so
$$
S\sim\mathcal N\left(\sum_i c_i\mu_i, \sum_i c_i^2\Omega_i\right).
$$
This applies no matter what the $c_i$ are and for any dimension of $X_i$.

---

The above part assumed $n < \infty$. If we have a countably infinite number of $X_i$ then whether or not the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i X_i$ converges depends on how the $c_i$, $\mu_i$, and $\Omega_i$ evolve and we can use [Kolmogrov's three series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) to understand when this happens.

---

I interpreted this to mean you wanted the distribution of a linear combination of Gaussians. If you meant a finite mixture of Gaussians then we can work it out in the following way. Let $f_i$ be the density of $X_i$ and let $S \sim \sum_{i=1}^n c_i f_i$ be the mixture distribution. You didn't state that $c_i \geq 0$ but I'll assume that so that this is a valid density. Then we have
$$
\text E[S] = \int s \sum_i c_i f_i(s)\,\text ds = \sum_i c_i \text E[X_i] = \sum_i c_i \mu_i
$$
as before, except now this represents a convex combination of the $\mu_i$ where that was not guaranteed before. I'll use $\mu_\text{mix} = \sum_i c_i\mu_i$ as the mixture mean.

For the variances we need
$$
\text E[SS^T] = \int ss^T \sum_i c_i f_i(s)\,\text ds = \sum_i c_i \text E[X_iX_i^T]
$$
so all together
$$
\text{Var}[S] = \text E[SS^T] - (\text E S)(\text ES)^T \\ =\sum_i c_i \text E[X_iX_i^T] - \mu_\text{mix}\mu_\text{mix}^T
$$
which is more complicated than $\sum_i c_i^2\Omega_i$

Comment: Thanks! This was my intuition & I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @CJR for sure! glad this helped

Comment: @CJR i just updated for the mixture case since it seems like maybe that's what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for updating the post. I am still but unclear how the last line produces the variance-covariance matrix for the resulting mixture bivariate normal? If you could clarify that a bit more I'd really appreciate it.  @jld

Comment: @CJR yeah sure. I'm using the result that for a random vector $S$ with mean vector $\mu$ the variance is $\text{Var}[S] = \text E[SS^T] - \mu\mu^T$. We know $\mu$ so the only remaining thing is the first term of $\text E[SS^T]$ and that's just the expected value of the 2x2 matrices $ss^T$ weighted by the mixture density

Comment: Thanks for expanding. I am still not quite sure how to calculate this expected value given the information I have (the weights $c_i$, the mean vector $\mu_{mix}$, the mean vector for each bi-var normal $\mu_i$, and the var-cov matrix for each bi-var normal $\Sigma_i$) . With that information, how do I calculate this expected value? Thank you! @jld

Comment: @CJR looks like you’ve got it but I’m happy to add any extra details if there’s any extra points that you’d like clarification on!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jld & @whuber for their answeres. Both were super helpful as I tried to solve this problem. With continued research, I found the post which I'll link below. It has the same info that jld & whuber shared, but it helped me solve it so I wanted to link it here

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195911/calculation-of-the-covariance-of-gaussian-mixtures